# Site Template name for Enterprise Document Center

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-template

If we go to 15/ hive, we can find site template name for team site "sts". Similarly what is the name for Enterprise Document Center site template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Get-SPWebTemplate cmdlet to get your template names.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607910.aspx.

Comment: Using that cmdlet without any parameters will list all of the currently installed templates.